# request for insect identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

A number of these insects have appeared in a house we are staying in on Fire Island. I would be grateful for any identification. Its length is roughly the width of the distal segment of my finger. A top and bottom view of the insect is uploaded.

[image: insect top view]

[image: insect bottom view]

Comment: Thanks for the identification.